# Pourquoi cette phrase n'est-elle pas au subjonctif "Et est-ce qu’il y a d’autres mots de notre langue qui viendraient..."

Tags: subjonctif, mode-grammatical, conditionnel

> C’est fascinant, hein ! Et est-ce qu’il y a d’autres mots de notre
>   langue qui **viendraient** aussi d’une langue très éloignée ?

Doit elle être écrite comme ceci ?

"Et est-ce qu’il y a d’autres mots de notre langue qui viennent aussi d’une langue très éloignée."

Un peu comme cet exemple:

> J'aimerais inventer quelque chose qui fasse une différence.

Comment: Je ne saurait pas répondre, l'emploi du conditionnel me parait tout autant valable. Dans ce cas particulier 'venir' ayant la même conjugaison au présent qu'au subjonctif cela pourrait porter à confusion peut être... Je n'arrive pas imaginer un exemple avec la seconde personne du pluriel pour confirmer ou infirmer cette idée.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux sont correctes. Tout dépend du sens que vous donnez à la phrase. Changez donc *venir* par *être*, vous pourrez dire:

> Et est-ce qu’il y a d’autres mots de notre langue qui seraient aussi
>   d’une langue très éloignée ?

On vient de nous donner un exemple, mais on se demande si c'est bien vrai. On est au conditionnel, donc beaucoup dans la doute. "Et il y en aurait d'autres comme ça, hein ?"

> Et est-ce qu’il y a d’autres mots de notre langue qui soient aussi
>   d’une langue très éloignée ?

Le subjonctif. On est toujours un peu dans le questionnement mais là on a accepté le 1er exemple. On se demande seulement si d'autres mots ont suivi le même chemin. "Parfait, je ne le savais pas, avez-vous d'autres exemples ?"
Et même :

> Et est-ce qu’il y a d’autres mots de notre langue qui sont aussi
>   d’une langue très éloignée ?

Le présent de l'indicatif. Le locuteur est persuadé (voir sait) qu'il y en a d'autres mais il demande à l'autre personne de bien vouloir les donner. "Comme XXX par exemple ?" et l'autre répondra "Mais oui, tout à fait et d'ailleurs..." ou "Mais non, pas du tout et d'ailleurs..."

Bref, vous n'avez que l’embarras du choix.
Attention, je ne dis pas qu'on peut *toujours* échanger le subjonctif, pour le conditionnel ou l'indicatif, mais dans le cas de votre phrase, oui.

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi mais je trouve aussi que l'indicatif a un style interview. Par contre la réponse peut tout à fait être négative. *Non, notre étude montre que…*.

Comment: Oui, en cherchant des phrases pour illustrer mon propos, j'ai imaginé une interview. Mais c'était déjà aussi un peu dans la phrase de user135711. Oui, la réponse peut être négative. Je modifie. Merci.